# How to groupby multiple columns in pandas and python?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, streamlit

I have a Dataframe that I want to perform a `groupby` with multiple columns.

If I select the columns via code, it works.

What I want is to allow the user to select from the list of columns, and return the `groupby result`.

when I add this line the system crashes and displays the below error:

```py
dda = df.groupby([primary_col_pyplot, [selected_column_names__pyplot]]) \
    .size() \
    .reset_index(name="count")
```

error:

```
 ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length
```

**Code:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

df = pd.DataFrame({"source_number": [11199, 11328, 11287, 32345,
                                     12342, 1232, 12342, 123244, 1235],
                   "location": ["USA", "USA", "USA", "INDIA", "INDIA",
                                "USA", "INDIA", "USA", "INDIA"],
                   "category": ["cat1", "cat2", "cat1", "cat1", "cat2",
                                "cat1", "cat2", "cat1", "cat1"],
                   })
df.head()

all_columns_names = df.columns.tolist()
primary_col_pyplot = st.selectbox("Primary Column To GroupBy", all_columns_names)
selected_column_names__pyplot = st.multiselect("Select Columns", all_columns_names)
dda = df.groupby(["category", "location", "source_number"])\
    .size()\
    .reset_index(name="count")
print(dda)
```

**Expected Result:**

```
    category    location    source_number   count
0   cat1         INDIA             1235       1
1   cat1         INDIA             32345      1
2   cat1         USA               1232       1
3   cat1         USA               11199      1
4   cat1         USA               11287      1
5   cat1         USA               123244     1
6   cat2         INDIA             12342      2
7   cat2         USA               11328      1
```

Comment: And how can we be of assistance? You have not really defined the problem. "what i want is to allow the user select from the list of columns and return the groupby reslut" And how? Where is the user input in your code?

Comment: @Betelgeux i am using streamlit where the user select from a dropdown list but i did not added i thought that the **list of columns**  is enough
i meant i need to replace the **columns name** that are in the **groupby function**  by the item that are selected from the **all_columns_names**

Comment: I think there is already a correct answer, but it depends on the input streamlit provides. If you somehow get a list out of it, and put it in the groupby method, it should work as intended. If it does not, please provide a repr output of the selected_column_names__pyplot object.

Comment: it return a list as example if user select category and location ==>  `selected_column_names__pyplot=["category","location"]`

Comment: @Betelgeux i tried your last comment but it display the below error:
`TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`

Comment: i tried you comment but still give the same error:
`selected_column_names__pyplot = st.multiselect("Select Columns",all_columns_names)
                selected_column_names__pyplot = [selected_column_names__pyplot] if isinstance(selected_column_names__pyplot, str) else selected_column_names__pyplot
dda=df.groupby(primary_col_pyplot+selected_column_names__pyplot).size().reset_index(name="count")`

error:` can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking up streamlit I will assume, that your st.selectbox provides only one string (one column to select).
And st.multiselect provides a list. (multiple columns to select). But if this might be incorrect, please try to debug it, and look at the values of primary_col_pyplot and selected_column_names__pyplot in different scenarios, to be sure.

So we have one string and one list of strings. Then the concatenated groupby would work as:

```py
dda = df.groupby([primary_col_pyplot] + selected_column_names__pyplot) \
    .size() \
    .reset_index(name="count")
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply this was the answer thank you.